# React with BroadcastChannel

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, broadcast-channel

In the React app I click on button to open new tab.
When I open new tab I want to pass some data to the new tab.

Code from my button component

```
const channel = new BroadcastChannel('color');

const handleClick = () => {
 ...
 channel.postMessage('GREEEENNNNNNNNN');
}
```

Code from new tab component

```
const [color, setColor] = React.useState('');

const channel = new BroadcastChannel('color');
  React.useEffect(() => {
    channel.onmessage = (msg) => setColor(msg.data);
  }, [channel]);

  console.log('color <========', color); // just to see that this is working
```

What I expect: I see 'GREEEENNNNNNNNN' in the console in new tab

What happening:

1. If I open only one new tab, I DON'T see 'GREEEENNNNNNNNN' in the console
2. If I open another new tab, I can see 'GREEEENNNNNNNNN' in the console of the first tab

Question: How to broadcast this value to new tab?

Answer (score 2):

To declare the Chanel

```
const channel = useMemo(() => new BroadcastChannel('color'), []);
```

To receive message

```
useEffect(() => {
        channel.addEventListener('message', (event) => {
             setColor(msg.data.color);

        });
    }, []);
```

To send message

```
channel.postMessage({
            color: 'red'
        });
```